# Trigger Validation of a related property (FluentValidation)

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have two properties in a class which are dependent on one another:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public DateTime EarliestDeliveryDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime LatestDeliveryDate { get; set; }
...
}
```

I configured the FluentValidation as follows:

```
using FluentValidation;
...

    public class SomeValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeClass>
    {
        public SomeValidator ()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.EarliestDeliveryDate).Must((order, earliestDeliveryDate) => earliestDeliveryDate < order.LatestDeliveryDate)
                .WithMessage("Earliest delivery date has to be before the latest delivery date.");

            RuleFor(x => x.LatestDeliveryDate)
                .Must((order, latestDeliveryDate) => latestDeliveryDate > order.EarliestDeliveryDate)
                .WithMessage("Latest delivery date has to be after the earliest delivery date.");
...
        }
    }
```

The validation for each property works as expected. However if the user enters an invalid date for both properties, then corrects one of the input fields (let's say EarliestDeliveryDate), the error message for the other property (e. g. LatestDeliveryDate) remains.

How to trigger the validation for all dependent properties, if the value of one property changes?

Comment: So, `LatestDeliveryDate` in this scenario has an invalid date?

Comment: @GregBurghardt The problem is, once the user corrects one of the properties, that would make both properties valid. But the validation rule will be evaluated only for the modified property, leaving the error message for the other property. I want to enforce the validation on both properties, if one of them changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to have you model class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and then raise the event in the Setter of all related properties like so:

```
public int LocationId
{
    get => locationId;
    set
    {
        locationId = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(LocationId));
        if (HazardId != default && MeasuredPersianDate != default)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(HazardId));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MeasuredPersianDate));
        }
    }
}
```

This way,if your UI is a framework like WPF or Xamarin Forms,as one of the related properties change,the validation will be triggered for the other ones as well automatically.However,If your UI framework doesn't refresh the view automatically when a `NotifyPropertyChanged` is raised,you need to subscribe to the event and have the UI trigger the validation for the related properties.For example in Blazor you can use the following code:

```
model.PropertyChanged +=
    (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName is null) return;
        form.EditContext!.NotifyFieldChanged(form.EditContext.Field(e.PropertyName));
    };
```

where `form` is the variable referring to the **EditForm** by using `@ref`

```
<EditForm @ref="form" Context="ctx" Model="model"OnValidSubmit="SaveChanges">...</EditForm>
```

Comment: Your proposed solution solved perfectly my problem. Marked as answered, thanks!
The UI framework is in this case Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` struct has a default value of January 1, 1 A.D. Perhaps the invalid date in the user interface is being posted back, and then ignored so the default for DateTime is used instead.

To fix this, you need to make each of those properties nullable by placing a `?` character after the name of the property type: `DateTime?`

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public DateTime? EarliestDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LatestDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then invalid dates would be `null`, worse case scenario. You only want to compare two dates if they both contain a DateTime object:

```
// If both fields are required:
RuleFor(x => x.EarliestDeliveryDate)
    .NotEmpty();

RuleFor(x => x.LatestDeliveryDate)
    .NotEmpty();

When(order => order.EarliestDeliveryDate.HasValue && order.LatestDeliveryDate.HasValue, () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.EarliestDeliveryDate)
        .Must((order, earliestDeliveryDate) => earliestDeliveryDate < order.LatestDeliveryDate)
        .WithMessage("Earliest delivery date has to be before the latest delivery date.");

    RuleFor(x => x.LatestDeliveryDate)
        .Must((order, latestDeliveryDate) => latestDeliveryDate > order.EarliestDeliveryDate)
        .WithMessage("Latest delivery date has to be after the earliest delivery date.");
});
```