# Trigger field validation when other field is changed using MudBlazor and FluentValidation

Tags: fluentvalidation, mudblazor

I have a form with two switches, in which I want to ensure that at least one of the switches is ON. I also want the validation error message to disappear from any of the switches if that condition applies, that is, if the other switch is updated to ON.

Currently I've only managed to get the switches to be validated independently, as this example shows https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQxkxmuxEyoZIVg

How can I force both switches to be validated (and their error message updated) when any of them is changed?

I've also tried to use this proposal (made for EditForm instead of MudForm) [Trigger Validation of a related property (FluentValidation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478566/trigger-validation-of-a-related-property-fluentvalidation) with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger validation on both the switches when any of them change by using the `CheckChanged` EventCallback [docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/switch#properties).

- Add a @ref for each `MudSwitch<bool>` and create their fields.
- Replace @bind-Checked with the `Changed` property (as this also uses the EventCallback).

```
<MudForm Model="@model" @ref="@form" Validation="@(model.ValidateModel)">
    <MudSwitch @ref="switchC" Checked="@model.IsC" For="@(() => model.IsC)" Color="Color.Primary" CheckedChanged="@(async (bool e) => { model.IsC = e; await ValidateSwitches(); })">C</MudSwitch>
    <MudSwitch @ref="switchS" Checked="@model.IsS" For="@(() => model.IsS)" Color="Color.Primary" CheckedChanged="@(async (bool e) => { model.IsS = e; await ValidateSwitches(); })">S</MudSwitch>
</MudForm>
@code 
{

    MudSwitch<bool> switchC;
    MudSwitch<bool> switchS;
    private async Task ValidateSwitches()
    {
        await switchC.Validate();
        await switchS.Validate();
    }
}
```

Now the switches will run your own validation logic when toggled and they will also be validated when the form is validated.

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcRkdGGIjocQhwI)

Comment: Both switches can be on at the same time. For me what is important is that the validation error message disappears on both properties if any of them is switched to on. For example if both are false and the model is validated, I'm ok with both error messages appearing, but if any of them is switched, then both error messages should disappear.

Comment: @700z I see, you can use [FieldChanged](https://mudblazor.com/api/form#eventcallbacks) event callback in the MudForm component to trigger the form.Validate() when any of the switches changes.  [mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQnudQlpBpFuhRR) Is that what you mean?.

Comment: no... sorry!! I don't want the whole form to be validated, because there will be other fields in the form and I don't want all error messages to appear when any of the other fields is modified. I just want IsC validation to be updated when IsS is modified, and viceversa. Still, your proposal made think about trying to have two forms: one for these two fields (and this one would be validated as you proposed) and another form for all the other fields. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @700z or you can try this approach. [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcRkdGGIjocQhwI). Here you use `Checked` and `CheckChanged` instead of `bind-Checked` and @ref the components individually instead of @ref the entire form. Then, run your own logic whenever any of the two switches changes in the CheckChanged eventcallback.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, a way of triggering a field validation manually. Thank you! Should I mark the whole answer as accepted?

Comment: @700z Great! I'll edit the answer to one that helped you.